# Unpacking list of arguments into parameters

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have a list in the following form:

```
list = {{a,1,3},{b,1,3},{c,1,3}}
```

Now I want to apply this list as parameters for the Sum function so that I end up with the following:

```
Sum[f[a,b,c],{a,1,3},{b,1,3},{c,1,3}]
```

But I don't know how to unpack the list like that. "Flatten" just gives a completely flat list.
Am I doing something here which you aren't even supposed to do?
What would be the most elegant way to do this?

In python for example I would just do this

```
Sum(f,*list)
```

Comment: Try `Sum[f[a, b, c], ##] & @@ list`. (Pretty sure this is a dupe.)

Comment: No this doesn't work. It doesn't give me a single sum but a list of sums

Comment: "a list of sums" - then there's something peculiar about your `f`. Without the code for it, it's hard to say anything more.

Comment: Using J.M.'s approach, look at `Clear["Global\`*"]; list = {{a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, {c, 1, 3}}; (Inactive[Sum][f[a, b, c], ##] & @@ list) == (Sum[f[a, b, c], ##] & @@ list)`

Comment: Yes my code was a little different. I forgot a bracket. your answer worked. Thank you